# Does rust have cancellation tokens the way C# has?

Tags: rust

In C# we have cancellation tokens which one of the most notable use cases are when you have an infinite loop doing something, and doing it while cancellation token is not called out to cancel the task. Usually, the thing which calls out to cancel a task is the OS itself (due to restart, or kill task or anything in between).

Currently I have an infinite loop in Rust as well and the application takes very long time to restart (I guess due to the fact I have loops that do not stop executions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

```rust
use std::io::Error;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};
use std::thread;
use std::time;
use signal_hook::flag;

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    // Declare bool, setting it to false
    let term = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false));

    // Ask signal_hook to set the term variable to true
    // when the program receives a SIGTERM kill signal
    flag::register(signal_hook::consts::SIGTERM, Arc::clone(&term))?;

    // Do work until the term variable becomes true
    while !term.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
        println!("Doing work...");
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(1));
    }

    // Since our loop is basically an infinite loop,
    // that only ends when we receive SIGTERM, if
    // we got here, it's because the loop exited after
    // receiving SIGTERM
    println!("Received SIGTERM kill signal. Exiting...");

    Ok(())
}
```